# VS Code or Chrome Dev Tools: debug NPM Workspaces (monorepo) TypeScript + React code

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I've got a monorepo setup using NPM Workspaces. It looks something like this:

- apps

  - my-react-app
- packages

  - shared-package

Both `my-react-app` and `shared-package` are rewritten in TypeScript. My React app launches on localhost:3000. I can use both Chrome Dev Tools and VS Code's debugger to break on code inside the main React app (ts and tsx files in `my-react-app`), but I can't get my breakpoint to hit in `shared-package`.

**Chrome Dev Tools**

I can see `shared-package`'s TypeScript files in Chrome Dev Tools (via source maps), but breakpoints there never get hit.

**VS Code Debugger**

With the following configuration inside launch.json:

```
{
  "name": "Launch Edge",
  "request": "launch",
  "type": "pwa-msedge",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

I can get breakpoints to hit in `my-react-app` but not `shared-package`.

How can I get breakpoints to hit in a monorepo package with either Chrome Dev Tools or VS Code's debugger?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but how is the code from shared-packages being run?  As imports within the react-application, which is being monitored by the debugger?

Comment: @SethLutske yes, exactly. The React application imports the compiled JavaScript file. Along with the compiled JavaScript file is a sourcemap that points back to the original TypeScript file. I provided more details of my setup here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66785791/188740

Comment: Ah.  The issue is probably that although you see your breakpoints in your sourcemap, that's not actually the code that chrome is running.  Check out [How to use breakpoints in sourcemaps (Chrome DevTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126009/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-sourcemaps-chrome-devtools), you may find some clues there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2020-01-18 Update:** Create React App released [v5.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0) and in it is:

> [#8227](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8227) Add
> source-map-loader for debugging into original source of node_modules
> libraries that contain sourcemaps (@justingrant)

With this change, the debugger will go deep inside source maps of modules, so for those of us lucky enough to use CRA, this problem is solved.

---

**Original Answer**

I got it to work, but sadly I'm debugging the compiled JavaScript and not the source TypeScript in the dependent packages (e.g. `packages/shared-package` from my example above).

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Attach React App",
      "url": "http://localhost:3030", // Or whatever port your app is running on
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/my-react-app"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's hard to find the file to attach a breakpoint to, but if you add a `debugger;` to the source TypeScript file, then VS Code will break on the compiled file. From that point forward, you can add as many breakpoints as you'd like in the compiled file and VS Code will stop on them.

Launch the debugger with <kbd>F5</kbd> and watch your debugger come to life:

[image]

**Note**: Adding a breakpoint to your react app (e.g. `apps/my-react-app`) will work as expected and you will be debugging your source TypeScript files. The problem of debugging the compiled files is only when you want to add a breakpoint to the dependent packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot but the only thing I can get from now is that **when I breakpoint on a package file it stops and show on the builded file with inaccurate line numbers**.

I managed to get to this point with ts-node-dev running my script and all `dist/` folders deleted (let me know if you want further details on this).

Another technique is to **put the breakpoint directly in the compiled `dist/` files**

It seems a problem with vscode debugger that do not **support nested sourceMaps**. This feature [is soon to be released](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1410) and I can't wait to try it! I'll keep you updated.

[Related issue: Unable to bind breakpoint in package in monorepo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1390)